# Rails SQL: How to join belongs_to association in query that is referenced twice with two foreign keys

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my app I have an `Event` model that basically represents a booking between two users. It has some basic attributes about the event as well as a `booker_id` and `bookee_id` which both represent foreign keys from the `User` table.

Basically I am trying to put together a search method for Events that allows me to search by the booker or bookee's first and last name. But I can't figure out how to reference BOTH the `bookee` user and the `booker` user in one single query. Below is my Event model showing the associations and a basic version of the Event search class method I've set up. Unfortunately, it only seems to reference the User table for Event `bookers` not `bookees`. I probably just need to review my SQL and write something a little uglier, but if anyone has a straightforward way to adjust that query so that it can include and reference the `User` table for both `bookee` users and `booker` users that would be super helpful.

event.rb

```
belongs_to :booker, :foreign_key => :booker_id, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :bookee, :foreign_key => :bookee_id, class_name: 'User'

def self.search(search)
  if search
    search_term = "%#{search}%"
    includes(:booker, :bookee).where(["users.first_name ILIKE :term OR users.last_name ILIKE :term OR event_title ILIKE :term", {term: search_term}]).references(:booker, :bookee)
  end
 end
```

user.rb

```
  has_many :booker_events, :foreign_key => :booker_id, class_name: 'Event', dependent: :nullify
  has_many :bookee_events, :foreign_key => :bookee_id, class_name: 'Event', dependent: :nullify
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a custom join trying to match those rows from the `users` table where their `id` is the same as the `booker_id` and/or `bookee_id` in the `events` table:

```
Event
  .joins('INNER JOIN users ON users.id IN (events.booker_id, events.bookee_id)')
  .where(
    'users.last_name  ILIKE :term OR
     users.first_name ILIKE :term OR
     event_title      ILIKE :term',
    term: term)
```

Comment: The table name is `users` so when I run a statement like that, that references `booker.first_name` or whatever else, I get errors that look like `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "booker"`